# How to obtain file link via POST request?

Tags: post, html

Say, if in a form there is a button that is linked to a file to download, in this case : code.taz
The HTML source code is below

```
   <form action="code.taz" id="download" method="post" name=
    "download">
           <input type="hidden" name="f1" id="tf1" value="0"/>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="download now"/>
                 </td>
```

Normally, one would need to click on the button to download the file ( POST submit method ). If I just visit http://example.com/code.taz , the page just returned 404.
Does that mean the file is not statically linked on the server or it may be but we cannot obtain it through direct Urls ?. If possible,  I would like to find out how I can obtain the file without visiting the webpage directly ?

Comment: They have server-side code that sends the file in response to certain POST requests.

Comment: Based on the HTML form I provided, how would craft the POST request ? My point is to see if I can download the file without visiting the page.

Comment: Look in the browser dev tools or in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Once you visit the URL typing it directly in browser address string, this is GET request. POST request is another type of requests this is why server logic returns 404 instead of file stream.